# Not able to change the text in french language translation in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, language-package

I installed a language pack of French of mageplaza it is successfully installed using composer and on my website language switcher is working fine but the issue is when i am changing the text that was still remaining to translate into french so i created fr_FR.csv into

> app/design/frontend/Theme/demo/i18n

**for testing it is working or not i tried to change 'Add to Cart' that is already translated to 'Ajouter au panier' so i changed it to csv to 'Ajouter au panier test' but not changing.**

I did cache flush and deploy content too.

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding new static text or displaying dynamic text, please print it using **' `echo __("static text"/$variable);` '** and update CSV file with what text you are going to translate and its translation.

**NOTE: please enter string or text as same as what is going to print with all spaces and font case, If any letter or space is missed then Magento does not accept that string.**

There is a second way - create separate blocks for each language and allocate them to respective store view, **no need of translation CSV file** for this way

Hope, It helps,

Thanks.

Comment: Actually i am trying to translate "About Us" text written in static block of footer links but not able to do this?

Comment: in this case, a second way is reliable, please create separate blocks for each language . for example - footer_block_English -> assign to English language store view and footer_block_French --> assign to French language store view... **NOTE:- no need to update CSV file. And each block contains respective language translation   & no need to deploy also**...

Answer (score 1):

As Kaustubh mentioned you should have all printed text static or dynamic in echo __("...") . You can do so and then enable on Configuration/Developer the Inline translation for the storefront! It will both show you what you can translate and will allow you to translate it!

P.S. everything that Inline translation shows you to translate can be translated with the csv method as well!

Comment: It is already written in file like echo__("....") it was translated first time to french when i installed the language pack but i am changing the text in fr_FR.csv but not getting any effect on that?

Comment: Disable your cash, deploy static content for fr and then re-enable the cash, see if this works
 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_FR --theme="vendor/theme" -s standard

Comment: I tried but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

If it is Static Block, you should make static block as per store view like make static block for english and same for french (same block id for both),
you can add content in english in "english" store view and french in "french" store view.

This is better way to do it.

Best Regards,
Krunal Pathak

Comment: Yes we can do this but here i want to know what is the issue of not getting change even i tried for 'Add to Cart' button to change it was translated by language pack of french but for testing i tried to change little text but not took effect?

Comment: I have tried it, on my side it work after clearing cache. you should clear cache from magento admin (all cache) and hard refresh your browser.

Comment: You tried so it is working fine at your end?

Comment: @CharulTyagi,
After installing mageplaza language pack, have you also added your csv file in given path?

Comment: when i installed mageplaza language pack a drectory created of mageplaza under vendor directory and there is also csv file that further i deployed using static content after that i taken effect of French but if i want to change any text again it is not working even copying to app/design/frontend/theme/demo/i18n

Comment: You need not to copy anywhere you have to just edit that csv file and get the result after cleaning cache. I am using mageplaza for chinese language and for me my method is working very well

Comment: what you did if you want to change text that is not still translated or change the translated text?

Comment: for not on csv file add that text and on next cell add translation like magento 1, here 2 more fields. 1 is for module or theme and 2 is for which module or theme add theme in first and in second add frontend/Magento/luma or your theme

ex.
About Us 关于我们 theme frontend/Magento/luma

Comment: where you edited the csv file can write the path here?

Comment: csv file that is inside mageplaza extension. 
/vendor/mageplaza/magento-2-french-language-pack/fr_FR.csv

Comment: ok i just edit the fr_FR.csv in location you told i changed the text of french "Ajouter au panier" to "Ajouter au panier test" but still "Ajouter au panier" this is showing i ran the deploy command to but no effect?

Comment: In same file
check whether it is more than one time or not. 
I think it is more than one time change them all. after that you need to just flush the cache and open it in private browser (or clear cache of browser)

Comment: i found in csv it is written on many places so i replaced with new one and then cache flush but no luck

Comment: this is the way to use csv file. hope you have tried in private browser.
if still not done you can try inline translate.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't translate the text, you can check where the text translated by follow steps below :

1. Navigate to the Admin Panel> Stores> Configuration :

[image]

2. Find the Developer tab under Advanced settings and preset it :

[image]

3. Open the Translate Inline options :

[image]

4. Set the ‘Enable for Frontend’ option to ‘Yes’ and click the ‘Save Config’ button :

[image]

5. check result on frontend

Comment: Yes i know this option to do this but the way by doing using csv should be working that's why i am researching to find where i did wrong.

Comment: Create the file fr_FR.csv  in your i18n folder then put your text need change by echo __('text')

Comment: I'm thinking your text has been translated in other file

Comment: i created fr_FR.csv file under app/design/frontend/theme/demo/i18n  and changed the text here.

Comment: And you don't see text changed ? seem another location have the text translated

Comment: No i did choose the theme my custom theme to french store to see effect but no luck!